# to display cols in vutify at the same line and aligned col with nex row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on project with vutify I have created a layout.
I want cols to display side by side as the figma  at the same line. Here is my result until now.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am sharing my code I want that col-2 doesn't go out, but to aligned at the same line with next row.

```css
.box-contact {
    background: url("./../assets/img/homepage-image/background.png");
    width: 692%;
    height: 105px;

}
```

```html
<template>
    <v-container grid-list-lg class="prodotti-cataloghi">
       <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12" md="5" lg="6" class="ma-0 pa-0">
                <h5>Prodotti </h5>
            </v-col>
         

             <!--<v-divider vertical class="vertical  hidden-sm-and-down ">  </v-divider>          -->

             <v-col cols="12" md="6" lg="6"  class="ma-0 pa-0">
              
                 <div class="box-contact text-center hidden-sm-and-down  d-flex flex-wrap">  
                       <p class="white--text">Lorem ipsum? Contattaci. +xx xxx xxxxx </p>  
                        <a class="phone-contact">
                        <img src="./../assets/img/homepage-image/Phone.png">
                        </a>                  
                </div>
             </v-col>
       </v-row>
       </v-container>
       </template>
```

Next in the secondly col I have made  css  to add background image in class
.box-contact but you can add what you want.
but secondly shouldn't to go out it should aligned with next row
I don't know if it is problem with width of image or
problem with cod.
Any idea?

Comment: what is `col-2` in your markup